# Mocking a Wcf ServiceContract

Tags: wcf, moq

I want to mock a ServiceContract. The problem is that Moq (and Castle Dynamic-Proxy) copies the attributes from the interface to the dynamic proxy which Wcf don't like. Wcf says: The ServiceContractAttribute should only be define on either the interface or the implementation, not both.

*Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The service class of type Castle.Proxies.IWorkOrderRequestServiceProxy both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type IWorkOrderRequestService. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types. If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute. Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute on type IWorkOrderRequestService to a separate interface that type IWorkOrderRequestService implements*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just experienced the same problem - so +1 for a solution! :-)

Update: http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/Proxy/CastleProxyFactory.cs contains a reference to a property (collection) called AttributesToAvoidReplicating, looks like a place to start looking in the Moq source code.

Update #2: Nailed it!

Add:

Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute));

before you wire up anything in your kernel.